# UIWebView webView:resource:canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:forDataSource:] + 92

Tags: ios, crash, web-thread

Crashed: WebThread
I found following crash logs how to resolve it? iOS version is 12.2.0 and device is iPhone 8 Plus.

```
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x22b9af530 objc_msgSend + 16
1  UIKitCore                      0x2592360b8 -[UIWebView webView:resource:canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:forDataSource:] + 92
2  WebKitLegacy                   0x236a4a190 CallResourceLoadDelegateReturningBoolean(bool, void (*)(), WebView*, objc_selector*, objc_object*, objc_object*, objc_object*) + 76
3  WebCore                        0x23608b6d0 WebCore::ResourceLoader::canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace(WebCore::ProtectionSpace const&) + 60
4  WebCore                        0x23608b650 WebCore::ResourceLoader::canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpaceAsync(WebCore::ResourceHandle*, WebCore::ProtectionSpace const&, WTF::CompletionHandler<void (bool)>&&) + 32
5  WebCore                        0x23546e900 WTF::Function<void ()>::CallableWrapper<-[WebCoreResourceHandleAsOperationQueueDelegate connection:canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:]::$_4>::call() + 136
6  JavaScriptCore                 0x2338bcaa4 WTF::dispatchFunctionsFromMainThread() + 288
7  Foundation                     0x22d2428d4 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 336
8  CoreFoundation                 0x22c74e2bc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
9  CoreFoundation                 0x22c74e23c __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 88
10 CoreFoundation                 0x22c74db24 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 176
11 CoreFoundation                 0x22c748a60 __CFRunLoopRun + 1004
12 CoreFoundation                 0x22c748354 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
13 WebCore                        0x2353a2480 RunWebThread(void*) + 600
14 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x22c3dc2c0 _pthread_body + 128
15 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x22c3dc220 _pthread_start + 44
16 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x22c3dfcdc thread_start + 4
```